# Saving an item in powershell after changing its contents?

Tags: powershell

I'm relatively new at powershell. Can someone help me with a simple script? Here is the script:

```
Clear-Host #clear command window
Set-Location c:\MyDir
Get-ChildItem -include *.txt -recurse  | Get-Content  | Foreach-Object {
                                                            $_  -replace 'TextToReplace1', '' `
                                                                -replace 'TextToReplace2', ''
                                                           } | Set-Content -WhatIf
```

Of course the last Set-Content is failing. I'm trying to save the txt file that i just changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do it like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -path c:\MyDir -filter *.txt -recurse | 
     Foreach-Object { 
                     (gc $_.FullName) | % 
                                        {
                                         $_  -replace 'TextToReplace1', '' `
                                              -replace 'TextToReplace2', ''
                                        } | Set-Content  -Path $_.fullname 
                    }
```

Comment: Thanks Christian. Though i didn't verify your solution would work but i'm sure it would by the look of it. Unfortunately, i didn't see it before i wrote my script. Yours would probably be more efficient too.

Answer (score -1):

This is how i ended up writing the script:

```
Set-Location c:\MyDir
$ProjFiles = Get-ChildItem -include *.txt -recurse  

foreach ($file in $ProjFiles)
{
    $NewFile = Get-Content $file.PSPath  | Foreach-Object {
                                                            $_  -replace 'TextToReplace1', '' `
                                                                -replace 'TextToReplace2', '' ` 
                                                           } 
     Set-Content $file.PSPath $Newfile                                                     
}
```